# How do i extract input values with the same name into a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I have a form that contains various productID values. They are contained in an input text, with different values all having the same name.

```
<%
ListIterator ul2 = myCartList3.listIterator(); 
while(ul2.hasNext()){ 
    ShoppingCart myCart2 = new ShoppingCart();
    myCart2 = (ShoppingCart)ul2.next();
%>
<input type="text" value="<%=myCart2.getProductID() %>" name="productID"   size="3" />
<% 
} 
%>
```

When the form is submitted, it goes to the servlet.  Usually I'd use `request.getParameter` but it only displays one attribute. How do I retrieve multiple attributes with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[getParameterValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String))

```
String[] productIDs= request.getParameterValues("productID");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) for `getParameter` clearly says

> You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).

And `getParameterValues` returns a `String[]`, which is what you want.